# ksh Auto-Completion PuTTY Configuration

Tags: unix, shell, putty, ksh, hp-ux

I'm having a bit of a problem configuring my `PuTTY` client to work with the auto-completion feature in the `ksh` shell.

I do a listing on the root with the directories `/home` and `/homeroot` and it returns the directories in a list just fine. I can't select it, though, by hitting X = (where X is the number).

```
/home/nitrodist>ls /h        #hits esc + =
1) home/
2) homeroot/
                             #hits 2 + = for the 'homeroot' dir
1) home/
2) homeroot/
                             #hits just the '=' key.
1) home/
2) homeroot/
```

Any ideas? I've `su -`'d to another user who can actually do it with their PuTTY session and I can't do it there, which makes me think it's a PuTTY configuration issue. This is running on a ksh93 shell on HP-UX, if that makes any difference.

Here's my ksh config:

```
/home/campbelm>set -o
Current option settings
allexport        off
bgnice           on
emacs            off
errexit          off
gmacs            off
ignoreeof        off
interactive      on
keyword          off
markdirs         off
monitor          on
noexec           off
noclobber        off
noglob           off
nolog            off
notify           off
nounset          off
privileged       off
restricted       off
trackall         off
verbose          off
vi               on
viraw            on
xtrace           off
/home/campbelm>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with PuTTY.

Try:

<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> then <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>

or

<kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Already tried the above line before and the second line was my gut instinct when I first started using `ksh`. Sorry, not at work until tomorrow to definitely test.

Comment: OK, just tried those commands and it definitely doesn't work.

Comment: @Nitrodist: The keystrokes I showed are for emacs mode. I should have asked whether you are using vi mode. What specific version of ksh (`echo $KSH_VERSION`)? Can you check to make sure the other user is using the same version? Your keystrokes work fine for me through PuTTY to a Linux system running 93t+. Are you using the regular number keys or the numeric keypad (try both)?

Comment: `>echo ${.sh.version}; Version M-12/28/93e` It's really bizarre. His version is the same. He had ignoreeof set to `on` in one case and it worked, and then ignoreeof set to `off` in another case which gave behavior similar to mine. So I set it to `on` but it didn't work. My numpad doesn't feature an equals key that works.

Comment: Well, it looks like there is a version difference between the AIX and HP-UX servers that we were testing it on. Version `E` doesn't work at all but version `T` does. Also, my shell had been set to `ksh` instead of `ksh93`, leading to much more confusion.

Comment: @Nitrodist: I meant the `2` on the numpad. It sounds like you must be on track for solving it, though.

Comment: `2 + Tab` works for me.